# Redirect_to from destroy not working in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, destroy

I had button_to element

`<%= button_to 'Destroy cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "btn btn-danger btn-mini" %>`

it needs to delete a object of Cart in online-store.

Here's destroy method

```
def destroy
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.destroy
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: "Now your cart is empty." }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
```

But when I clicked my button Rails said that I have no template "destroy.html.erb". I created it. And Rails always redirect me to this page. I tried to write redirect in the end like this

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { notice: "Now your cart is empty." }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
redirect_to store_url
```

In my mind it must destroy my @cart and then redirect. But I get on destroy.html, and cart still there.

I need you help guyz, thanks a lot))

**UPD:** Here's screen of rake routs
http://postimg.org/image/y1h1pzpsp/

**UPD2:** Log is here:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5CgJPSign_YWFhNRWw5bk9hZXc/

**UPD3:** Cart Contoller

```
#encoding: utf-8
class CartsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

# GET /carts
# GET /carts.json
def index
  @carts = Cart.all
end

# GET /carts/1
# GET /carts/1.json
def show

end

# GET /carts/new
def new
  @cart = Cart.new
end

# GET /carts/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /carts
# POST /carts.json
def create
  @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @cart.save
      format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @cart }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /carts/1
# PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @cart.update(cart_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# DELETE /carts/1
# DELETE /carts/1.json
def destroy
  @cart = current_cart
  @cart.destroy
  session[:cart_id] = nil
  redirect_to store_url
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_cart
    begin
    @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      logger.error "Trying get access to null cart."
      redirect_to store_url, notice: "Invalid cart."
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json {render json: @cart}
    end
  end
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def cart_params
    params[:cart]
  end
```

end

Comment: Can you post your rake routes?

Comment: Can you show the log?

Comment: @MarekLipka already in post

Comment: @endifix link for google docs is definitely not what I expected.

Comment: @MarekLipka log of last request: http://postimg.org/image/3o9g19n83/

Comment: Please paste (in your question) whole `CartsController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of your error is `set_cart` method. I guess you should remove:

```
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json {render json: @cart}
```

part.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot!!! It works!

If you can, please tell me reason of it? Cause I have no idea why it's blocked my requests.

Comment: @endfix because `respond_to` block renders response. If you don't specify, how it should be rendered (or where redirected), Rails try to render template with name according to current action name - in this case, it is `destroy` template.